# Como poner un div al lado de otro infinitamente?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

No se si se entienda, lo unico que necesito es que todos los `div`s esten uno al lado del otro, sin que ninguno se posicione por debajo del resto.

Tengo el Siguiente ejemplo:

```css
div.linea {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #4800ff;
    overflow-x: scroll;
}
 
div.linea > .itemlinea {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 20px;
    background: #4800ff;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="linea">
    <div class="itemlinea">Item 1</div>
    <div class="itemlinea">Item 2</div>
    <div class="itemlinea">Item 3</div>
    <div class="itemlinea">Item 4</div>
    <div class="itemlinea">Item 4</div>
    <div class="itemlinea">Item 4</div>
    <div class="itemlinea">Item 4</div>
    <div class="itemlinea">Item 4</div>
    <div class="itemlinea">Item 4</div>
    <div class="itemlinea">Item 4</div>
    <div class="itemlinea">Item 4</div>
    <div class="itemlinea">Item 4</div>
    <div class="itemlinea">Item 4</div>
    <div class="itemlinea">Item 4</div>
    <div class="itemlinea">Item 4</div>
    <div class="itemlinea">Item 4</div>
    <div class="itemlinea">Item 4</div>
    <div class="itemlinea">Item 4</div>
    <div class="itemlinea">Item 4</div>
    <div class="itemlinea">Item 4</div>
    <div class="itemlinea">Item 4</div>
    <div class="itemlinea">Item 4</div>
    <div class="itemlinea">Item 4</div>
    <div class="itemlinea">Item 4</div>
    <div class="itemlinea">Item 4</div>
    <div class="itemlinea">Item 4</div>
    <div class="itemlinea">Item 4</div>

</div>
```

Como veran el resultado despues de unos cuantos `div` estos se bajan, lo que deseo es que todos queden afilados en forma horizontal y yo lo recorrería con el scroll que tengo ahi.

Nota: utilizo bootstrap.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Puedes utilizar la clase `d-flex` de Bootstrap para que todo se ubique en la misma fila; mientras no utilices la clase `flex-wrap` el contenido seguira expandiendose.

Con esto tambien puedes deshacerte de las reglas `display: inline-block` pues cada elemento dentro del contenedor principal se convierte en un `flex-item`.

Bootstrap 4 esta hecho completamente en Flexbox, puedes apoyarte de muchas utilidades y para saber mas de su comportamiento puedes leer esta documentacion:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/flex/

```css
div.linea {
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #4800ff;
    overflow-x: scroll;
}
 
div.linea > .itemlinea {
    padding: 20px;
    background: #4800ff;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="linea d-flex">
    <div class="itemlinea">Item 1</div>
    <div class="itemlinea">Item 2</div>
    <div class="itemlinea">Item 3</div>
    <div class="itemlinea">Item 4</div>
    <div class="itemlinea">Item 4</div>
    <div class="itemlinea">Item 4</div>
    <div class="itemlinea">Item 4</div>
    <div class="itemlinea">Item 4</div>
    <div class="itemlinea">Item 4</div>
    <div class="itemlinea">Item 4</div>
    <div class="itemlinea">Item 4</div>
    <div class="itemlinea">Item 4</div>
    <div class="itemlinea">Item 4</div>
    <div class="itemlinea">Item 4</div>
    <div class="itemlinea">Item 4</div>
    <div class="itemlinea">Item 4</div>
    <div class="itemlinea">Item 4</div>
    <div class="itemlinea">Item 4</div>
    <div class="itemlinea">Item 4</div>
    <div class="itemlinea">Item 4</div>
    <div class="itemlinea">Item 4</div>
    <div class="itemlinea">Item 4</div>
    <div class="itemlinea">Item 4</div>
    <div class="itemlinea">Item 4</div>
    <div class="itemlinea">Item 4</div>
    <div class="itemlinea">Item 4</div>
    <div class="itemlinea">Item 4</div>

</div>
```